# Showing latest item at the bottom of ListView android

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I have a ListView whose items I fetch from a JSON response. Currently the latest item is added at the top of the ListView. I want it to show at the bottom of the ListView and also scroll to the bottom as it is added.

Here is my code:-

MainActivity.java

```
 items = new FetchItems().execute(getRequest).get();


LinkedList<HashMap<String, String>> getList = new GetList().execute(items).get(); 
                itemsAdapter = (ListAdapter) new CommAdapter(NewDetails.this, getList);

                commentsList.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
Collections.reverse(aList);
```

Where aList is your listview.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This may help you.

```
commentsList.post(new Runnable(){
  public void run() {
    commentsList.setSelection(commentsList.getCount() - 1);
  }});
```

or use the properties for your list view in your xml

```
 android:stackFromBottom="true"
 android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
```